# two way data binding between view and controller mvc5

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am writing the web application which allows you to optimize SQL query.

I have such a view:

```
<div id="codeeditor" style="margin-right:20px; float:left"  >
    <script>
        var editor = CodeMirror(document.getElementById("codeeditor"), {
        mode: "sql",
        theme: "dracula",
        tabSize: 5,
        lineNumbers: true,
        });
        editor.setSize(500, 500);
    </script>
    <input type="submit" value="start" id="btnClick" />
</div>

<div id="codeeditor1">
    <script>
        var editor1 = CodeMirror(document.getElementById("codeeditor1"), {
            mode: "sql",
            theme: "dracula",
            tabSize: 5,
            lineNumbers: true,

        });
        editor1.setSize("45%", 500);
   </script>

</div>


@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#btnClick").click(function () {
            var f = {};
            f.url = '@Url.Action("Demo", "Home")';
            f.type = "POST";
            f.dataType = "json";
            f.data = JSON.stringify({ sourceSqlCode: editor.getValue() });
            f.contentType = "application/json";
            editor1.setValue(@ViewBag.readyQuery);
            f.success = function (response) {
                alert("success");
            };
            f.error = function (response) {
                alert("err");
            };
            $.ajax(f);
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Here is my controller which handles button clicking

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Demo(string sourceSqlCodee)
    {
        //here I use my libraries and optimize query

        ViewBag.readyQuery= optimizedQuery;

        return View();
    }
```

All I need Is to pass query to controller by clicking the button and pass it back to the view after modifying into the codeeditor1

It simply doesn't work because scripts are being run earlier than my controller method. How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you should just return a string in your controller action, like:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Demo(string sourceSqlCode)
{
    //here I use my libraries and optimize query

    return optimizedQuery;
}
```

Then, in your AJAX success method, do something like:

```
f.success = function (response) {
    editor1.setValue(response);
};
```